# State equation variables in the Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I've been trying to fit a State-Space model using the Kalman Filter following an economics paper. It's a multivariate model, and in several state equations they include *contemporaneous* values of other state variables. However I tried to implement this in two different software packages and they both specify that one cannot include contemporaneous values of other state variables in a state equation, only lags of it. Is there any mathematical reason why this cannot be done?